# Switching to different domain registrar and different host without any website or email downtime

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, domain-registrar

What I currently have:

- Domain registered at register - oldregister.com
- Website hosted at different host - oldhosting.com
- Email hosted at different email provider - oldemailhosting.com

What I want:

- Domain registered at new register - newregister.com
- Website hosted at new host - newhosting.com
- Email continued to be hosted at old email provider- oldemailhosting.com

What I the current plan is:

1. Unlock domain, get auth code and transfer domain ownership to
   newregistrar.com  from oldregistrar.com
2. Leave current ns at ns1.oldhost.com
3. Setup hosting at newhosting.com and wait 5 days for domain ownership to transfer to newregistrar.com
4. Once domain is transferred all web/email should still work because no ns/records have changed and the oldhosting.com account is still active
5. On newhosting.com create a new DNS zonefile keeping all the records within (a, cname, mx) the same
6. At newregistrar.com change the ns to ns1.newhost.com so it reads the zonefile/records on newhosting.com.

What my concern/question is:

Is there any error in these steps that may cause website/email downtime?

oldregistrar.com uses 3rd party dns at ns1.oldhosting.com so no need to change dns to ns1.newhosting.com until after transfer to newregistrar.com is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Set up [Namecheap Free DNS](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/freedns.aspx) for the domain, and move all your existing DNS records, before you transfer the domain from the previous registrar.

When you *do* transfer the domain, Namecheap will integrate the free DNS with the incoming domain.

Comment: I have not used Namecheap Free DNS because I that would require me changing to NS to freedns1.registrar-servers.com before the transfer. I believe the Free DNS service is intended for domains using current registrars ns, which this domain does not.

If I transfer just the ownership and the dns is not using the old registrars NS (i.e. ns1.OLDDOMAINREGISTRAR.com) than i won't have any downtime right? Because the old ns1.OLDHOST.com and zone file will still be working until the new ns1.NEWHOST.com updates world wide.

Comment: Your statement doesn't make sense. I thought you were intending to transfer your domain registration to Namecheap?

Comment: Yes the domain will transfer to namecheap as the registrar but web/email hosting is elsewhere.

Comment: No, you need to bring over the DNS to Namecheap _first_, and then transfer the domain registration.

Comment: If i change the ns to from ns1.currenthost.com to freedns1.registrar-servers.com services I might as well change it to ns1.newhost.com instead no?

Comment: Or would it be better to transfer to namecheap with old zone file, records and ns in place. Once transferred (after 5 days) duplicate the records on namecheap and then switch the ns to ns1.newhost.com once hosting is set. Sorry for the long wording, downtime can cause major issues.

Comment: @AnthonyPhelps If you are trying to host your DNS at a third party, why do you want to host it at Namecheap? You really should clarify your question to explain what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: thank you for your response/patience as I flesh out the correct question. I hope my rewriting helps clarify what I am trying to accomplish, and what my concerns are.

Comment: @AnthonyPhelps It still isn't clear what you intend to do with the DNS.

Comment: I intend to recreate the existing zone file and change the dns server to use ns1.mediatemple.com: "... change the ns to ns1.newhost.com so it reads the zonefile/records on newhost.com."

Comment: Again, you need to edit your question. You name a dozen different domains and it's not clear which is which.

Comment: The ones with old in them are old and the ones with new are new. I'm trying to generalize because the specific host shouldn't matter.

Comment: That's the point. [You went too far with obfuscation](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) and now it doesn't make any sense. If you're going to obfuscate at all, at least make sure everything is consistent.